# What type of object is the ReferenceType in an instanceof RelationalExpression?

Tags: java, semantics, instanceof, boolean-expression

In practice, Java expects an object for an input and output for much of its semantics, whether it be primitive types or actual objects, excluding such class metadata as type names, argument lists, and return types

Being inherently an OOP language, everything is treated as an object on an abstract level, whether or not everything is stored as an object in memory

So, I was wondering, what sort of object is the [ReferenceType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-ReferenceType) in the production, [RelationalExpression (instanceof)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-RelationalExpression)?

For example, in the following expression:

```
object instanceof ReferenceType
```

I want to know if `ReferenceType` is an actual object or not, and if not, how is it represented by the JVM according to the JVM specification as bytecode and how does it function?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking: it's a reference type. Just like `String` in `public String foo()` is a reference type.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, I understand that, but I suppose my question is what kind of object a ReferenceType is and whether or not it is purely metadata or an actual object.

Comment: It's not an object, it's not metadata. It's just the name of a type.

Comment: Then a ReferenceType is just a runtime constant value in the ConstantPool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ReferenceType is a symbolic reference. `instanceof` has a corresponding `instanceof indexbyte1 indexbyte2` instruction according to the Java Virtual Machine Specification (Java 10). The two index bytes can be constructed into a 32-bit (unsigned) integer that is an index to the current class's runtime constant pool.

> The objectref, which must be of type reference, is popped from the operand stack. The unsigned indexbyte1 and indexbyte2 are used to construct an index into the run-time constant pool of the current class (§2.6), where the value of the index is (indexbyte1 << 8) | indexbyte2. The run-time constant pool item at the index must be a symbolic reference to a class, array, or interface type.

Where the objectref is the left-hand object reference in an `instanceof` expression.

The symbolic reference is resolved if the objectref is not null, and the objectref's type is evaluated against the resolved type to determine if objectref is an instance of ReferenceType:

> If objectref is null, the instanceof instruction pushes an int result
>   of 0 as an int onto the operand stack.
>
> Otherwise, the named class, array, or interface type is resolved
>   (§5.4.3.1). If objectref is an instance of the resolved class or array
>   type, or implements the resolved interface, the instanceof instruction
>   pushes an int result of 1 as an int onto the operand stack; otherwise,
>   it pushes an int result of 0.

Comment: ReferenceType is not a symbolic reference. It is a mere non-terminal symbol of Syntactic Grammar

Answer (score 2):

> In practice, Java expects an object for an input and output for
>   everything,

Well no, that's an overstatement.  Even if we exclude syntax elements such as punctuation and keywords, Java has values of primitive type.  And it has type names.

> and, being inherently an OOP language, everything is
>   treated as an object,

You're getting yourself into trouble by blithely throwing around the word "everything".  I think you're trying to assert that in an OO language all *data* are represented inside the program by objects.  At least that's the closest plausible interpretation I can reach, and it is in fact true of some OO languages (SmallTalk, Ruby, ...) -- but not of Java.

> so I was wondering, what sort of object is the
>   ReferenceType in the production, RelationalExpression (instanceof)?

It is not an object.  It is a type name.

> How is it represented in the JVM at runtime?

I would have to check to be sure, but very likely it is represented by a reference into the constant pool of the class in which the expression appears.

> What sort of objects can
>   be passed to this Expression, if any, if usually a type is used in
>   Declarations such as class declarators or variable declarators?

The right-hand operand of an `instanceof` expression is a type name, just as, indeed, is used in class and variable declarators.  It is not a value, neither of reference nor of primitive type.

> Is it
>   a "meta-object" that only represents a real type or class,

The Java language does not have a concept of "meta object", at least as distinguished from objects of type `java.lang.Class`.  But objects of type `Class` are still objects, and references to them are not suitable for use as the right-hand operand of `instanceof` expressions.  The right-hand operand must be a type name.

> and why
>   would the developers of Java not allow passing a Class object in place
>   of a ReferenceType, or am I thinking in the wrong paradigm for
>   instanceof?

I can't speak authoritatively to the motivations of Java's designers, not being one of them.  I do observe, however, that `Class.isInstance()`, available since Java 1.1,  serves the same purpose that allowing a reference to a `Class` as the right-hand operand of an `instanceof` expression would do.

The right-hand operand of `instanceof` must be a type name.

Comment: I would imagine that the intentional leaving out of passing a Class object or a ReferenceType is purposely part of the design of the Java language, and that `Class.isAssignableFrom()` does have its purpose, but if it were used interchangeably with `instanceof` then why is it not `Class.isSubclass(Class<?>)` or `Class#instantiates(Object)`? Unless of course, it was unintentional and the developers somehow overlooked the possibility of `RelationalExpression instanceof ClassLiteral`.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer, the behavior implied by the name `isSubclass` is different from that of `instanceof` and `isAssignableFrom` when the type in question is an interface.

Comment: It still makes semantic sense to use `Interface.isSubclass` since an Interface is essentially an abstract class with protected constructor and no concrete methods or declared fields.

Comment: What is your objective here, @LinkTheProgrammer?  I'm not interested in debating whether the Java designers could or should have made different choices in this area.  Reasonable people can disagree.  You asked a factual question about `instanceof` expressions, and I answered it.  If my answer is unclear in some way then by all means feel welcome to ask for clarification.

Comment: The equivalent to `instanceof` would be rather `Class.isInstance(…)`, not `Class.isAssignableFrom(…)`.

Comment: @Holger, yes, `Class.isInstance()` is the reflective analog of the `instanceof` operator, but read my comments more carefully.  `Class.isAssignableFrom()` is the reflective analog of *what the OP was asking about*: a hypothetical `instanceof` operation with a type instead of an object as the left operand.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don’t see that question about the left operand anywhere. The question’s text and title talk about “`ReferenceType`”, the right hand side of the `instanceof`.

Comment: @Holger, my bad, you are correct.  I have updated the answer.